# Enabling Audit log in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to enable audit logs in geoserver. Apparently there should be a `monitoring/` directory within the data directory. It should then contain the file `monitor.properties`.

I cannot find this directory in any of the later versions. If i try to manually create, restart then load some WFS layers no log files are being generated.

Anyone able to give advice?

Its very sparsely documented. I was going from this example https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/auditing.html and http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/audit.html

I've checked versions `2.10`, `2.11` and `2.13`. None of these versions had a `monitoring/` directory.

Here is the content of the `monitor.properties` file I created:

`audit.enabled=true
audit.path=[PATH TO FOLDER]
audit.roll_limit=20`

EDIT: ok... Ignore this... I don't have the Monitoring extension installed. I didn't realise I needed it!

Comment: we encourage you to answer your own question (in detail) rather than pose an edit in the question. Please add an answer with a bit more information that you've given.

Comment: Yep will do, just wanted to get it working first before self answering